# How can I add 2 and 4 to odd numbers in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function

I am a beginner in Javascript now I have started, the only background I have is HTML and CSS. I'm trying to make a program that prints whether a number is even or odd. But to the odd numbers to add 2 and 4. My code :

```
function isEvenExceptTwoOrFour(number) { 
if (number%2 == 0  ) { 
 
 
    console.log("The number is even");}

 
else { 
    console.log("The number is odd ") 
} 
 
}
```

Comment: Ok, what’s your question? Why not just compare `number` to `2` or `4`, for starters? What research have you done? Can you share the code you’ve written in an attempt to meet this requirement as a [mre]? [ask]

Comment: 2 based in what, or 4 based in what, do the if then number += 2, and do a return statement at the end of the function `return number`

Comment: Your statement “how to add” is quite ambiguous. Do you mean you want to perform addition of `2` and `4` with the odd number that’s been input? Or do you mean that `2` and `4` should be considered as “odd”?

Comment: @esqew i  mean that 2 and 4 should be considered as “odd”.

Comment: Ok, great. Why don’t you show us what you’ve tried as a [mre], then? The code you’ve provided doesn’t seem to include an attempt on your part to satisfy the requirement you describe as is required by [ask]. What research have you done? Do you know how to compare a variable to a constant number?

Answer (score 2):

You could write an [`if..else`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) statement like this, using [`Logical Or (||)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR) to check each of your conditions.

Below I used the statement

```
if (number === 2 || number === 4 || number % 2 === 1)
```

This checks if `number === 2` or `number === 4` or `number % 2 === 1` (if the number is odd)

**Code:**

```js
function isEvenExceptTwoOrFour(number) { 
  if (number === 2 || number === 4 || number % 2 === 1) {
    console.log("Number is considered odd");
  } else {
    console.log("Number is considered even")
  }
}

isEvenExceptTwoOrFour(1);
isEvenExceptTwoOrFour(2);
isEvenExceptTwoOrFour(6);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation and for your time you helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Write a function that accepts an array of exceptions, and returns a new function that accepts a number. The closure (the function that's returned) will then 1) check to see if the number is in the array, and return false otherwise 2) check to see if the number is even, and return true, otherwise 3) return false.

```js
// Pass in the exceptions array and return a function
// that will accept a number
function checkIsEvenExcept(exceptions) {
  return function (n) {
    if (exceptions.includes(n)) return false;
    return n % 2 === 0 && true;
    return false;
  }
}

const exceptions = [2, 4, 18];

// Assign the result of calling `checkIsEvenExcept` with the
// exceptions array to a variable. This will be the function that
// we can call
const isEven = checkIsEvenExcept(exceptions);

// We can now call that function with a number
// that we need to check
console.log(isEven(6));
console.log(isEven(2));
console.log(isEven(1));
console.log(isEven(4));
console.log(isEven(8));
console.log(isEven(18));
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without writing the return function (n) {} ?

Comment: All the other answers provide that solution @Eliasbasilakopoulos.

Answer (score -2):

You can just add conditions whether the number is 2 or 4.

```
 function isEvenExceptTwoOrFour(number) { 
   if ( number === 2 || number === 4 ||| number % 2 !== 0){
      console.log("The number is odd ") 
      return 
   }
   console.log("The number is even") 
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation and for your time you helped me a lot.

Comment: Slight issue of the syntax error

Comment: I wanted to ask, if I want to add a number from the keyboard with the prompt how do I do it?